# Excel User form - Read Only but still fuctional

Tags: excel, vba, user-controls

I have created a userform for my job that will be utilized by my whole dept.  I am wondering if there is a way to upload my Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet to a shared drive and make it:
1. "read-only" so it cant be changed
2. still performs functions
3. Accessible to multiple users at the same time

Thank you!

Comment: Password protect your macros, then save it as a `.xltm` (Excel Macro-Enabled Template)? Protecting the Userform or the contents of the workbook? Also can set **password to modify** during a Save As. etc.

Comment: Thank you! Does this allow multiple people to use the form at once?

Comment: If it's a Template, by default if people double click it, Excel creates a new one based on it. The approach will depends on requirement. If userform makes changes that needs saving and affects others, just use **Share Workbook** in Review tab, Changes group. I haven't tested if more than one Save at the same time though.

Comment: Your question about multiple users is impossible to answer for sure, without knowing what you form does.